# Mac Mini PHP Warning

Tags: php, macos

When I type php -v in the terminal on my mac mini I get the following error message:

"PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/pdo_pgsql.so' - dlopen(/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/pdo_pgsql.so, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0 PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/pgsql.so' - dlopen(/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/pgsql.so, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0 PHP 5.5.29 (cli) (built: Sep 6 2015 20:20:34) Copyright (c) 1997-2015 The PHP Group Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2015 Zend Technologies"
To update PHP I run the following: curl -s http://php-osx.liip.ch/install.sh | bash -s 7.0 and it appears like it install successfully; however, when I check the version php -v; I keep getting the same error message. I'd appreciate some assistance with this issue. Thanks

This is not a duplicate.  None of the other "similar" questions (answers to them) solve this problem for me.  I kindly asking for help.  Please don't mark this questions as a duplicate; because its not a duplicate.

Comment: Yes, this is a duplicate. **You** posted the *exact* same thing earlier. This has nothing to do with it being a Mac mini. You have a broken PHP install. See my comment on your original post for my suggestions.

Comment: You mentioned in the *duplicate* question comments that you brewed php56, yet this is 5.5.29, so you must be running either the apple distribution or some other version you may have installed previously. Try to add this line to your .bash_profile : `export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH`, then open a new terminal and issue php -v, see if that cures your issue.